# Stop fixed position div from overlapping

Tags: html, css

I added a fixed div. to my header at the top in order to make it stay in place, but other elements keep overlapping it.

I tried using suggested fixes such as using a z-index, but the behaviour of these ruins my modal pop-ups.

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening? I added a margin-bottom but that doesn't do the trick either.

Here's the code I have:

```
.home-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-social.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aladin" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block head-extras %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md home-header">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand">
          <h1 id="logo" class="nav-wel">Pomodoro</h1>
        </a>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <div class="status">Balance:&nbsp;{{ request.user.profile.coins }}<img class="coin-img" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="40px" width="auto"></div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle welcome nav-wel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="welcome">Welcome {{ user.get_username }}</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/shop">Shop</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/change-password">Change Password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/pomodoro.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Overlapping fixed div]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 top level DIVs - one for header, and second for content. Any other stuff must be under content div. If you want your popups to be shown under header - just use absolute position on popup, and set relative to content DIV. Like this:

```
<div id='header' style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:30px;background:pink'>
    Header
</div>
<div id='content' style='position:relative;margin-top:30px;background:green' >
    Content...
    <div id='popup' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:100px;width:100px;height:100px;background:yellow'>Popup</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Fixed_positioning) takes the element out of the flow of the rest of the page, so it will overlap unless you position everything else carefully around it - and even then, because `fixed` positions relative to the *viewport* not the *document*, as soon as the user scrolls all bets are off.

If you want to keep it in the flow of the page so that other elements are positioned around rather than behind it, don't use `position: fixed` (or [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Absolute_positioning) which also allows overlap).